# Godot GDScript Typing: Invalid Type Err

Tags: godot, typing, gdscript

most basic example:

world.tscn (main-scene)

```
extends Node2D
const MYLIST = preload("res://my_list.tscn")

func _ready() -> void:
    var my_list = MYLIST.instantiate()
    add_child(my_list)
    my_list.initialization(["one", "two", "three"])
```

and
my_list.tscn

```
extends Node2D
@onready var item_list: ItemList = $ItemList

func initialization(entries: Array[String]):
    for entry in entries:
        item_list.add_item(entry)
```

this gives me runtime-error: *invalid type in function "initialization". The array of argument 1 (Array) does not have the same element type as the expected typed array argumen.*

The argument i pass into my_list.initialization is clearly a Array[String]
If i remove the type hint from the func declaration it works as expected.

Can someone explain whats wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Godot?

Comment: My Godot Version: 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know which version of Godot you are using, I would like to know so I can test in that specific version.

I can tell it is Godot 4 because you have typed `Array`s but the details have changed from version to version.

If I recall correctly in Godot 4.0 this failed silently (no error, but you got an empty array), and after Godot 4.2 it seems to be working correctly. Thus, 4.1, probably?

---

Godot does not have typed `Array` literals (although in recent versions it will scan the contents of the array to find if the literal is compatible with a typed `Array`).

So the `Array` given by `["one", "two", "three"]` is not a `Array[String]` but simply a `Array`, and your version of Godot might not be checking if it is compatible.

---

So, aside from trying in a more recent version. I have three possible workarounds for you:

- Revert the parameter to `Array`:

  If you do not use a typed array `entries: Array` you would not have this problem. However you would be losing type information.

  Internally you can use `assing`:

  ```
  func initialization(entries: Array):
      var my_typed_array:Array[String] = []
      my_typed_array.assign(entries)
  ```

  Or convert the items to `String`:

  ```
  func initialization(entries: Array):
      for entry in entries:
          item_list.add_item(str(entry))
  ```
- Declare the `Array[String]` in another line:

  If you declare a variable to be `Array[String]` it might work:

  ```
  var tmp:Array[String] = ["one", "two", "three"] 
  my_list.initialization(tmp)
  ```
- Declare the parameter as `PackedStringArray`:

  If you declare the parameter like this: `entries: PackedStringArray`, Godot should be able to do the conversion automatically. *This is what I remember doing when I faced the problem.*

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer! actually i am on latest 4.2.1! Can you confirm that my code is working with your godot version? Im also facing strange behaviour that autocomplete does not work as i expect: in "world.tscn" the "initialization" function name ist found but he does not display the signature of this func (name of argument(s), types). Maybe bad editor settings?? (i turned on text_editor/completion/add_type_hints and lowered text_editor/completion/idle_parse_delay to 1.5 but rest sould be default settings..?)

Comment: @user14534957 I had not considered that. Since you have the `PackedScene` but not the script, Godot does not give you all the type information (`instantiate` returns `Node`, but what kind of `Node`?). What I do is cast the result of `instantiate` to the script type (since you do not have a `class_name` you would also `preload` the script in a constant, and cast to that). I'm on the habit of typing everything (including `-> void`), it didn't even ocurr to me you would not be getting autocomplete.

Comment: superb, you solved a big mystery for me! its working as you described. seems verbose that you always have to load both (if you dont want to clutter global namespace). this should work somehow with one command load-scene-and-attached-script .. one last thing: is there any benefit to include -> void ?

Comment: @user14534957 There has been proposal on improving that, it seems they need a way to annotate the `PackedScene` so they can read the script without loading it. Yes, there is a benefit to having a return type even if it is `-> void` or `-> Variant` (i.e. returns anything): if you declare `-> void` Godot will mark as error if you have a `return`, and if you declare `-> Variant` (or some type) Godot will mark as error if there is a branch that does not lead to a `return`. So it leads to better static analysis.

Comment: @user14534957 To clarify, the type of the root node of the `PackedScene` needs to be carried along, so `instantiate` returns that type. If it gets implemented with generics we would be able to declare `PackedScene[NodeType]`. Anyway, that would probably take a good while before being added to Godot.